# JQM: Include header on all pages or not?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a rather extensive mobile site using JQM (1.1.0). The structure is built to make ajax-fetching as smooth as possible. Until now I've included the header (html-tag, header-tag and all imports of scripts) on every single file / page.

Struggling with some caching issues and events not firing I stumbled across [this post](http://rip747.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/pitfalls-with-jquery-mobile-and-how-to-over-come-them/) (#1), 
saying that the header only should be included once in the first document / file that will be loaded. This works great and also solved many of the caching issues I previously had.

However this has also created a quite nasty problem: If the user hits refresh it breaks the site completely - as the necessary document tags are missing from all but the first page.

So, is there any way to handle this gracefully or should I revert and go back to the JQM Doc way of including the header in all pages? I would feel more comfortable with the latter, but the author of the above post has a good point - at least in my opinion.

Or to rephrase, does JQM truly ignore the header on fetching pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but the solution I finally went for was a single, global header.

It turns about JQM does indeed ignore the header. This still left the refresh problem, but this was solved with a simple javascript redirect back to the splash screen that contained the full header.